# The parent process keep trace of it child's termination status

Tags: c, unix, process

I am reading up on the `wait` and `waitpid` functions and came across the following text:

> When a process terminates, either normally or abnormally, the kernel notiﬁes the parent by sending a `SIGCHLD` signal to the parent.
>
> Then the parent should handle the termination.

I am confused about *why* the parent has to know its child is terminated. Surely, if the child has already terminated, it is gone and will never consume any resources.

For what reason does the parent have to be aware of it?

Comment: Beware the attack of the zombies — processes that don't know how to handle the termination of their children are apt to create zombies.  There are ways to avoid that, but you need to know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a process is starting other processes, it *normally* want to keep track of their state.

When a child process terminates, it *almost* disappears entirely. It becomes a zombie process and just enough information is kept around for another process (usually the parent) to be able to tell *why* it terminated (basically, its return code).

Then, when the parent successfully does a `wait` on the child, the return code is returned and the last remnants of the child are cleaned up.

And a parent doesn't *have* to do this. There are ways to start a child process that will have its parent modified, you can see the difference between:

```
sleep 3601 &
( sleep 3602 & )
```

The latter starts a child shell and, from within that, starts the sleep, then the child shell exits, so that child gets a *new* parent:

```
1 /sbin/init splash
|
+-- 1121 /usr/sbin/lightdm
    |
    +-- 1846 /usr/sbin/lightdm --session-child 12 19
        |
        +-- 2078 /sbin/upstart --user
        |
        +--- 29899 sleep 3602
        |
        +--- 2929 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
             |
             +--- 2935 bash (my bash shell)
                  |
                  +--- 29891 sleep 3601
```

You can see here that *one* of the `sleep` processes still has my shell as the parent but the other one has been pushed up the process tree to `upstart`.

Often, it gets adopted by `init`<sup>(a)</sup> which has code specifically for reaping the zombies (`wait`-ing on them then throwing away the return code).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Modern UNIXes can override this with a call to `prctl()` with the `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` argument. This marks a process as a sub-reaper.

Then, when a parent dies, the fist sub-reaper when walking up the process tree becomes the new parent of its immediate children (with `init` being the ultimate reaper).

You can actually see this in the above process tree where it's evident that `upstart` has done exactly this. That means *it* was the first sub-reaper found when walking up the tree so the `sleep` that belonged to the process that died didn't go all the way up to `init`.